# Webpack dynamic 1 to 1 input/output

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want to create a rule in `webpack.config.js` that allows me to compress all the .js files inside one directory, and output them into another one. For that, I'm using webpack's UglifyJsPlugin.

For example:

```
── src
│   ├── js
│   │   └── a.js
│   │   └── b.js
│   ├── minified
│   │   └── a.min.js
│   │   └── b.min.js
```

Where `js` is the directory where I'll have my input files (entries), and `minified` the directory where I want to output the minified ones (output).

As it says in the title, I want it to be "dynamic", which means that I don't want to specify the entries one by one, I just want to specify the directory and output them using something dynamic like `filename: [name].min.js`.

Answer (score 1):

That is not the kind of task for what webpack is made for... but:

```
{
    entry: fs.readdirSync('./js').reduce((res, fn) => {
        res[fn] = fn
        return res
    }, {})
    output: {
        path: './minified',
    },
}
```

Comment: I know, this is just a special case... for the rest of the project I use it as it's intended :P

Comment: Just to clarify... the concept is good, but you missed filename in output. It should be `filename: "[name].min.js"`